# Invalid JSON error when I add non ASCII characters to Twitter API v2 rules

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I use the Java class that Twitter provides in its GitHub for the filtered stream endpoint (https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/FilteredStreamDemo.java) and it works fine.

However, when I add in a rule a word that contains non ASCII characters (for example the word "siccità") it returns the error:

> {"errors":[{"parameters":{},"message":"Invalid JSON"}],"title":"Invalid Request","detail":"One or more parameters to your request was invalid.","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/invalid-request"}

I tried to convert the word to UTF-8 but it did not work at all. Is there any way to add words with non ASCII characters to the Twitter API v2 rules in Java?

Comment: ```httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");``` might make a difference. Seemingly the default encoding of HttpClient is ISO-8859-1

Comment: "it did not work at all" - was there an error from the API? Also, I wonder whether you have tried the same rule but (if possible) with one of the samples in a different coding language in that same GitHub repo, or submitting the rule via Postman or curl?

Comment: @g00se I tried it but it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It might help to know *exactly* what you tried

Comment: I tried to add httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"); as you suggested and it did not work

Comment: @AndyPiper the problem exists only in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class FilteredStreamDemo.java that Twitter provides here: https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/main/Filtered-Stream/FilteredStreamDemo.java you have to go to the class createRules and replace this line of code:

```
StringEntity body = new StringEntity(getFormattedString("{\"add\": [%s]}", rules));
```

with that:

```
StringEntity body = new StringEntity(getFormattedString("{\"add\": [%s]}", rules), "UTF-8");
```

and it will work fine even when there are non ASCII characters in the rules.